# Is it possible to dynamically render return value of a function without using state?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a chat application to learn Redux and have been having some difficulty in determining whether I need to use state to render the result of a db function call dynamically.

The required functionality is to have the channel name appear in the header when a user selects one of the channel links in the sidebar. The images below demonstrate this functionality in action.

In this image, no channel has been selected yet and so no channel name is visible in the header.

[image]

In this image the user has selected general in the sidebar and so it is populated within the header dynamically.

[image]

I have managed to get the functionality I desire to work by using state via hooks and so am aware that I can easily port this over into Redux. My question is whether I needed to use state at all? Below is a CodeSandbox link which shows the app with the required functionality in place.

- CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-solomon-0ro4e

Prior to using the hooks state, I was attempting to return the channel name from the `getChannelName` function like so:

```
    const getChannelName = () => {
        if (currentChannel) {

            console.log(currentChannel);

            const channel = firestore.collection("rooms").doc(currentChannel);

            channel.get().then((doc) => {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    return doc.data().name;
                } else {
                    console.log("No such document!");
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error getting document:", error);
            });
        }
    }
```

I then made many different attemps to render the result from this function within my return statement, but all of my attempts led to the channel not being populated in the header. Following this I pushed it into state and of course it works right away. Is it possible to render the channel name in the header without storing the value in state?

Thank you!

Comment: I added the `firebase` tag so maybe some firebase experts can chime in.  There is a package `react-redux-firebase` that can help automate a lot of the setup.

Comment: The root of the problem with your implementation is that the getChannelName function does not return anything. Inside your then clause you are returning the name of the channel if it exists. However, you're returning from the anonymous arrow function not from getChannelName itself, so in essence, getChannelName always returns undefined. Even if you changed this logic to return the correct value, it would be an async operation and thus you probably would need some sort of hook or state mechanism to wait for the promise to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Mariano, I've just had a play around with async/await and as you have said - impossible without awaiting the promise to resolve. Assuming there is no way to do this without using state then it appears it is the only way to proceed.

Comment: State is like the oxygen of react, attempting to write codes to avoiding using state, when it's so conveniently available is just..., anyway if you are writing chat application then you should be exploring using the firestore listeners in useEffect.

Comment: "Is it possible to render the channel name in the header without storing the value in state?" It might be possible in some convoluted way or by going down to direct DOM manipulation, but... why would you want to do that? What is the problem you have with storing the value in the state?

Comment: React components rerender when state and/or props update. If you skirt storing anything in state (to update) or to pass as a prop then you really aren't React-ing right. Your UI is a static snapshot and visual representation of your state.